# IE9 Rendering Left-To-Right mark

Tags: silverlight, right-to-left

In my Silverlight application I am formatting dates in a right-to-left language with the following format string:

```
"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"
```

The month name is made up of right-to-left characters which rearranges the formatted string and inserts the time in the middle of the date. To get around this I tried inserting the unicode U+200E and U+200F characters. This worked to some extent but IE9 is rendering the control character! It looks almost like a little 'up-arrow'. Has anyone come across this before or know a way round it?

Apologies, I don't have access to a screenshot of this. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Ian

Answer (score 0):

In whatever you're using to display the date (e.g. TextBlock), you need to set FlowDirection = RightToLeft if you know there are going to be RTL characters in the string.